# Upload a large File to Sharepoint in a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have tried what seems like about a dozen different methods of uploading files to sharepoint from a silverlight application.  They either have severe limitations (file size limits of less than a meg or so) or lots of security issues that I have not been able to over come.  I have tried:

- WCF (We are trying not to use any custom WCF services at all FYI though this is the method that I have gotten to semi work)
- Sharepoint Web services
- Client object model
- HTTP put
- Webclient write stream

I have seen lots of different examples out there of people doing completely different things but none seem to work and all seem like they are the "old" way of doing things.  I am using silverlight 4, sharepoint 2010 on IIS 7.  Is there a best practice for uploading large (say 20-30 meg) files?  I just want to dump a file into a document library.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Tweaking web application level setting from central admin, changing asp.net limit in web.confit and following article helped me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I have tried the ways of upping the maximum upload size suggested there and it doesn't seem to work for me.  What am I missing here?  I found a second method of upping the max size and tried both at the same time then running an upload and I still get a 400 bad request error.

Comment: The second method he suggests (using the save binary direct method) works great but isn't available in silverlight.

Comment: Also keep in mind that IIS7 has a filter limitation of 30 MB.  I was bitten by this a few weeks ago.  You need to go into IIS 7 and set this to a large size or an HTTP Handler will kill the request at 30 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a thought silverlight has a thing called an HTML Bridge which allows it to interact with the rest of the page.  Consider calling a javascript function from Silverlight, and let the javascript function do the actual upload

UPDATE - the Javascript ClientOM doesn't seem to have the SaveBinaryDirect method :-(
How about doing some ExecuteQueryAsync and then in the success call back function (no longer on the UI thread), using the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client version of File?  I know this would require downloading the larger assembly, so perhaps that's not so good.

I wonder if there is a way to get the clientOM use a more efficient binding when calling the web services...

Martin

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts, I'll have to play around a bit when I get back to this project.

Answer (score 0):

The default upload size limit for the SharePoint client object model is 2 MB. You can change that limit by modifying the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` property of the service.

This can be done in two ways:

- programatically - as described in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff599489.aspx#Y796) - tho this won't work in Silverlight for example
- trough the powershell. On the server where you have SharePoint installed, fire up the SharePoint Management Shell (make sure you run it under the farm administrator account) and run the following commands.

  $ws = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
  $ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 52428800

  $ws.Update()

This will change the upload limit to 52428800 bytes - or 50 MB. Now, restart the website hosting your SharePoint site (or the entire IIS) for the changes to take effect.